# simple c program keeps crashing

Tags: c, scanf, crash-reports

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int a,b,c;
printf("Enter values of a,b,c:");
scanf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);

printf("\nDescending order of the numbers entered:");

/*Test for Biggest Number*/
if((a>b)&&(a>c))
 printf("%d",a);
else if((b>a)&&(b>c))
 printf("%d",b);
else if((c>a)&&(c>b))
 printf("%d",c);

 /*Test for Second Biggest Number*/
 if((a>b&&a<c)||(a<b&&a>c))
  printf("%d",a);
 else if((b>a&&b<c)||(b<a&&b>c))
  printf("%d",b);
 else if((c>a&&c<b)||(c<a&&c>b))
  printf("%d",c);

/*Test for Smallest Number*/
if((a<b)&&(a<c))
 printf("%d",a);
else if((b<a)&&(b<c))
 printf("%d",b);
else if((c<a)&&(c<b))
 printf("%d",c);

 return 0;
}
```

this is a c program in which 3 numbers are entered and the program prints the in descending order. i compiled the program and the ran the program.after entering the three numbers the program would just crash. is there something wrong with my code or do i have to add something?

Comment: Wrong: `scanf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);`.  Better: `scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);`.  C parameters are pass by value.  So you need to pass the *address* of your variables (so scanf knows where to put the data).

Comment: Please add space after `;` and `,`   write an expression like `if((b>a&&b<c)||(b<a&&b>c))` as `if((b > a && b<c) || (b < a && b > c))`  make it readable, and improve indentation.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you are not passing the address of your variables to `scanf`. Change

```
scanf("%d %d %d",a,b,c)
```

to

```
scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:-

```
scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c)
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d %d %d",a,b,c)
```

as `&` refers to the address of your variables.

In C the parameters are passed by value so you need to pass the address (or pointer). When you pass the address (or pointer) then scanf knows where it has to put the value.

Comment: this is complete answer.

Comment: @RahulTripathi; `& is required to get the values from the user`: Not always!